# C++ pointers doubts

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a doubt about this code I saw at the university.

```
struct nodeList{
  int data;
  nodeList * next;
};
typedef nodeList * List;

void filter( List &l )
{
   List * aux = &l;
   while(*aux)
   {
       if( (*aux)->data > 3 )
       {
          List toDelete = *aux;
          *aux = (*aux)->next;
          delete toDelete;
       }
       else
       {
          aux = &((*aux)->next);
       }   
   }
}
```

- I don't know, what does `List * aux = &l;` actually do. Because `List` is the same as `nodeList *` so, the code would be `nodeList * * aux = &l;` and that is actually what I don't understand, is that a pointer to a pointer that holds the address of a pointer of a `nodeList struct`?
- The second thing I have trouble understanding is the last line. `aux = &((*aux)->next);`
  Why is `aux` without a `*` on the left side? if It was declared as `List *aux = &l;` is `List` just a pointer to the first node?

Thank you in advance. I googled a lot, but I didn't find any answers. If you can answer my questions I'll appreciate a lot.

Comment: Perhaps the line: `typedef nodeList * List;` was meant to be written as `typedef nodeList List;` And then a lot of things seems understandable.

Comment: no, that line is with the *
I typed this and it works. gets rid of the values higher than 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Exactly.
2. You should always match the datatypes. `aux` is a `nodeList **`, therefore any assignment should be of the same datatype. Since `((*aux)->next)` is `nodeList *`, you use the `&` operator to get a `nodeList **`.

**Datatypes**

Variables have specific datatypes. For example, `aux` is a `List*` but `List` is an alias of `nodeList*`, so `aux` is a `nodeList**`.

But also expressions have datatypes as a whole. For example,

- the expression `((*aux)->next)` is of datatype `nodeList *` and `&((*aux)->next)` is of datatype `nodeList **`. You use the operator `&` to get the memory address of a variable, and the result data type of using `&` is one more star.
- the expression `*aux` is of datatype `nodeList *`, because aux is `nodeList **` and the star operator gets the value of the pointed element by the pointer, effectively removing one star from the datatype.

Comment: I dont understand sorry... 
(aux is "nodelist *") and "*aux" is "nodelist **"
or not?

Answer (score 2):

```
void filter( List &l )
```

This means "pass by reference" rather than "by value", i.e. pass a pointer to the object l rather than copy l to the stack. In terms of how it actually works on a computer, there is no difference between "void filter( List &l )" and "void filter( List *l )" as they both end up being pointers passed to a function. From a coder's perspective, however, "void filter( List &l )" has the advantage that the complier ensures you won't get a 'nullptr'.

```
List * aux = &l;
```

This means "give me a pointer to object l". The symbol "&" is used for many different things in C/C++, and in this context it means "give me the address of". `aux` is a pointer to an object of type List, not an object of type List (of course List here is itself a pointer to nodeList).

```
aux = &((*aux)->next);
```

`*aux` is the object pointed by aux, which is a "nodeList*". `(*aux)->next` is the next pointer in the nodelist object pointed to by the List object pointed at by aux. `aux = &` sets the aux pointer to point to this object.

This code segment isn't particularly clear or concise, so I'm assuming it's written this way as an educational tool to see if you understand pointers, references, and address of in C/C++. As such, perhaps you should review the definitions of these operators in a tutorial on pointers in C/C++.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I understood the last line better after I realised that the first line could be written as

    List * aux;
    aux = &l;

I did not take in consideration that when you do List * aux = &l;
you are doing those two lines. 
thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

> - I don't know, what does `List * aux = &l;` actually do. Because `List` is the same as `nodeList *` so, the code would be `nodeList * * aux = &l;` and that is actually what I don't understand, is that a pointer to a pointer that holds the address of a pointer of a `nodeList struct`?

It takes the address of the pointer equivalent from the reference parameter (thus is the same as a `nodeList**` actually).

> - The second thing I have trouble understanding is the last line. `aux = &((*aux)->next);`
>     Why is `aux` without a `*` on the left side? if It was declared as `List *aux = &l;` is `List` just a pointer to the first node?

`aux` is a reference, so the original pointer passed as parameter `l` will be changed.